# How to generate grayscale PAM file using imagemagick?

Tags: image-processing, command-line, imagemagick

It is trivial to generate P5 PGM / P6 PPM using imagemagick, using simply

```
$ convert -depth 12 -size 512x512 xc:white white12.pgm
$ convert -depth 12 -size 512x512 xc:white white12.ppm
```

Which correctly gives:

```
% head -3 white12.ppm white12.pgm
==> white12.ppm <==
P6
512 512
4095

==> white12.pgm <==
P5
512 512
4095
```

Now I am struggling to get [PAM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pam.html): P7 + Grayscale working, all I could find is:

```
$ convert -depth 12 -size 512x512 xc:white white12.pam
```

which gives the `RGB` one:

```
% head -7 white12.pam
P7
WIDTH 512
HEIGHT 512
DEPTH 3
MAXVAL 4095
TUPLTYPE RGB
ENDHDR
```

How can I generate the `GRAYSCALE` PAM one ?

---

I did report a bug upstream, maybe there is something bogus in my imagemagick version:

- https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/5027

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug here in **ImageMagick**. This might be a workaround:

```
magick -depth 12 -size 512x512 gradient: -colorspace gray -compress none pgm:- | awk '
   NR==2 {w=$1; h=$2}     # pick up and save height and width on line 2
   NR<4  {next}           # ignore lines 1-3
   NR==4 {printf("P7\nWIDTH %d\nHEIGHT %d\nDEPTH 1\nMAXVAL 4095\nTUPLTYPE GRAYSCALE\nENDHDR\n", w,h);}
   1                      # pass remaining lines through unchanged' > result.pam
```

That produces this:

```
P7
WIDTH 512
HEIGHT 512
DEPTH 1
MAXVAL 4095
TUPLTYPE GRAYSCALE
ENDHDR
65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535 65535
```

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick, to create text format NetPBM files, add -compress none.

```
convert -depth 12 -size 512x512 xc:white -compress none white12.pam

head -7 white12.pam
P7
WIDTH 512
HEIGHT 512
DEPTH 3
MAXVAL 4095
TUPLTYPE RGB
ENDHDR
```

Comment: Fred, I think you need `-colorspace gray` in there to get the grayscale that OP wants, but then IM ignores the `-compress none` and goes all binary...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I overlooked the grayscale part. Thanks Mark.